# Заставить реагировать canvas под dom элементом

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, dom

Суть: Есть canvas фоном. На нем расположены кнопки. Анимация канваса завязана на движение мыши. Когда наводишь на кнопку - анимация застывает. Как сделать чтоб не застывала. Вот здесь реализовано так, как мне нужно, но я не могу понять как: http://2f-design.fr/themes/starry/

Answer (score 1):

Если интересно решение, то это: обернуть все в один контейнер. Поставить на него обработчик движения мыши, делегировать event на canvas. Поставить обработчик движения мыши на canvas и сделать ему stopPropagation.

Answer (score 0):

может я вас неправильно понял, но за это отвечает библиотека [header-pointer](http://2f-design.fr/themes/starry/wp-content/themes/starry/js/header-pointer.js?ver=1.0)

Отсюда следует, что надо ковырять ее.

Она вроде jquery Не использует...

подробнее могу посмотреть завтра, просто у меня уже час ночи, глаза слипаются...